# What is this device called?

Tags: single-word-requests

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but here we go... I'm looking for a word for a device that I can only describe from memory. I'm not sure what it's called or even what it was used for, but it's very distinct.

The object in question is some sort of pipe that can blow wind. You have two handles that you need to push against each other in order to create the wind, and the device itself is small and can be used by one person. It's a very old-fashioned device I've only ever seen in old cartoons, and I think it was used to free up chimneys or to blow air on a fireplace to make the fire stronger or something.

What is this device called? I tried finding it on Google, but I didn't have any luck there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**bellows**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/bellows)

> a. An apparatus for producing a strong current of air, as for sounding
>   a pipe organ or increasing the draft to a fire, consisting of a
>   flexible, valved air chamber that is contracted and expanded by
>   pumping to force the air through a nozzle.

[image]